# Creating and Working with a Class of Classes

Tags: python, class, oop

I have inherited some Python code that contains a class that is designed to get a series of objects from a running application using their API. However, I am struggling to work out the best way to handle those objects within my class.

I was thinking of dividing this class into two classes:

- the first to contain a group of these objects
- a second for the individual objects

Within the second class, there would be a number of methods that act as wrappers around the api calls - this is to make it easier for users of the library I am working on.

At the moment, I have a class similar to below. This is the bare bones of what I have

```
from xyz import api

class GroupOfObjects():
    def __init__:
        # Set some attributes
        self.objects = self.get_objects()

    def get_objects(self):
        objects = api.service.Objects()
        
        # In order to convert objects from the API, I need to put them into
        # a python list
        return [object for object in objects]

   def get_object_name(self, object):
        # object.name is available through the api
        return object.internalclass.internalfunc.name
```

In order to loop through each of the objects to get the names or other properties of the objects I have to call:

```
objects = GroupOfObjects()

for x in objects:
    if objects.get_object_name(x) == 'abcdef':
        # Do something
```

This seems quite clunky. I do have methods in my class that returns a list of all the names. But this is just a list of strings.

What I would like to do is access a single object in the GroupOfObjects class and access the attributes and methods of it without needing to do a for loop.

Can anyone suggest better ways to handle this?

An alternative I had in mind would be to rewrite the whole module so it has a function that returns back a list of the individual objects. However, this would break existing functionality. But if this is the best way, then I would be happy to do it.

Comment: Store them in a dictionary instead of a list?

Comment: Do you have a second class defined? When you said divide into two classes, I thought maybe you would do `[My_Object(object) for object in objects]`

Comment: I don't have second class defined yet. All of the methods in the GroupOfObjects class act similar to `get_object_name` or use a list comprehension to generate a list of properties e.g names, dates, etc. Just want to explore options before refactoring or re-writing what I have

Answer (score 0):

How about for now, we define a method on your class to iterate over the API objects and find the one you seek.  Maybe something like this:

```py
class GroupOfObjects():
    def __init__(self):
        self.objects = list(api.service.Objects())

    def get_object_by_name(self, name):
        for obj in self.objects:
            if obj.internalclass.internalfunc.name == name:
                return obj

objects = GroupOfObjects()
obj = objects.get_object_by_name('abcdef')
# Do something
```

You still have a for loop, but that is hidden from the uses of your class.